# Storing and posting multiple rows of data ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am converting a project from ASP.net Forms to ASP.Net MVC Core.

Consider the following form:
[image]

I'm creating a new recipient, and that recipient can have multiple contact methods.

The Add Contact Methods button brings up the following Modal:
[image]

In my ASP.Net forms app, I had a repeater, and I just added a new element to the repeater, and then when the form was submitted, I would iterate through the repeater's rows and populate my database.

How would one do this in MVC?  Do I just create an html table and iterate through those rows?

I am new to MVC, so I am not sure how to proceed here.

For reference here is my data model for recipients and their contact methods:

```
public class Recipient
{
    [Key]
    public Guid RecipientGUID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Company { get; set; }

    public UserGroup Owner { get; set; }

    public List<ContactMethod> ContactMethods { get; set; }

    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public User LastModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastModifiedOn { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

}
```

Contact Methods:

```
public class ContactMethod
{
    [Key]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public Guid ContactMethodGUID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please specify a type.")]
    public ContactMethodType Type { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Recipient Recipient { get; set; }

    public int CountryCode { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a identifier.")]
    public string Identifier { get; set; }

    public bool IsPreferred { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for options to dynamically add collection items

Answer (score 2):

You use Razor syntax in your .cshtml view file.

```
<table>
@foreach var recipient in model.Recipients 
{
    <tr><td>@recipient.FirstName</td></tr>
}
</table>
```

Look up a ASP.NET MVC Razor tutorial

Comment: @recipient.FirstName

Comment: @Ya I was thinking, because I am in an @{ //code} block that I do not need the @...

Comment: Thanks for that, but how would I add a new row to the collection?  Can razor do that? or do I have to call the controller, and post the data back?

So I have a recipient, and I want to add a telephone and email to their contact methods list.  that is the part that is getting me.

Comment: Yes you need to post data back to server to add a telephone number